# Perform dismissModalViewControllerAnimated or popViewControllerAnimated based on segue identifier?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, segue

I have 2 views connecting to 1 view, 1 view is push and another is modal.
Is it possible to get the segue identifier and perform either dimiss or popview?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get back to the segue that pushed/presented you unless you store it yourself.

However, you can look at your `presentingViewController` and `navigationController` properties.  If you were pushed, `presentingViewController` is nil and `navigationController` is non-nil.  If you were presented, `presentingViewController` is non-nil and `navigationController` is nil.